# How to make Win10 recognize external SSD

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive

I'm planning to upgrade the SSD in my Lenovo X1 Carbon 5th Gen.  I bought a Samsung 860 EVO SATA M.2 1TB drive and a QNINE M.2 USB 3.0 B-key enclosure so I could clone my current drive first.  But Win10 doesn't seem to be recognizing the new SSD.  I went into MANAGE|STORAGE|Disk Management and I see 2 drives.  Disk 0 appears to be my current, original drive.  Disk 1 appears to be the new SSD.  When I first went in there it said it wasn't initialized, so I did that. But nothing seems to happen after that.  When I right click on it, the only options not greyed out are to convert it to MBR or dynamic or go go offline.  What should I do now?

Comment: You should just clone to the disk. No need to make any change to it. The cloning software will overwrite it anyway. The fact that the disk shows up in disk management is enough, really.

Comment: Oops.  You're right.  I went back into my cloning software and now it works.  If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll select it. - Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just clone to the disk. No need to make any change to it. The cloning software will overwrite it anyway.

The fact that the disk shows up in disk management is enough, really.